# How prevent round second in datetime substraction?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to calculate a subtraction between two timestamp columns with overlap:

```
begin                       end                         Duration
2019-10-21 07:48:26.740378  2019-10-21 07:48:28.272688  1.532   
2019-10-21 07:48:26.923764  2019-10-21 07:48:28.449916  1.526
```

I managed to deal with the temporal overlap to have the correct result, but I have a format problem.
I have this result when I used these:

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].where(~c2, (df['end'] - df['end'].shift()).dt.seconds)
```

I don't understand why pandas rounds the result to zero with `dt.second`

```
Duration
1.532
0.000
```

But I would like:

```
1.532
0.177
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: I juste have the result in second with no (precision) decimal (example : 13.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) (just like when working with `datetime` objects directly):

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].where(~c2, (df['end'] - df['end'].shift()).dt.total_seconds())

                        begin                        end  duration
0  2019-10-21 07:48:26.740378 2019-10-21 07:48:28.272688       NaN
1  2019-10-21 07:48:26.923764 2019-10-21 07:48:28.449916  0.177228
```

Comment: yeah the result display with X,XXXe^x seconds. Thanks !